# CSS Parse Error

Tags: html, css

I am receiving a CSS parse error when validating my CSS. I've been stuck on this for two days...what am I doing wrong? Please and thank you.

This is what the error says: **Parse Error [ --> #credits]**

Here is the W3C report with the CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=motorcitypawnbrokers.com&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

I'm only concerned with the Parse error for #credits

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I see an HTML comment just above the `#credits` rule in your stylesheet:

```
<!-- Credits -->

#credits {
    clear:both;
    float:none;
    background-color:#F00;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    height:35px;
}
```

That should've of course been a CSS comment like the rest of your comments:

```
/* ------------ Credits ------------ */

#credits {
    clear:both;
    float:none;
    background-color:#F00;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    height:35px;
}
```

And here's another one just above `.clear`:

```
<!-- Stuff -->
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an html comment in there when CSS uses C-style comments (`/*` and `*/`)